# New and improved reputation skew synchronization broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-graph, synchronization

Are the reputation skew updates that were announced on [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes) broken?

I have hit the rep cap for today but the reputation lost for a delete is not showing up in the [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded?tab=reputation) - the highlighted value should be +10 instead of +2:

[image: reputation page showing the problem]

The reputation audit page has the right values:

[image: reputation audit showing the problem]

I have not triggered a manual recalc so the issue can be seen.

Additionally, note that the upvote I am talking about was made over an hour before, so its not like I am not waiting patiently.

---

Update:

Looks like this is OK now on my reputation page, not sure if as result of a manual recalc or the [latest updates](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).

---

Update:

This is still happening. I deleted an upvoted answer earlier today (now migrated), but the profile page has been showing the wrong value (10 rep too much) all day, though the number at the header was right. Now that I've almost reached the rep cap, it has gone screwy on the header as well.

Profile page:

[image: reputation page showing discrepancy]

Audit page:

[image: reputation audit showing discrepancy]

Comment: And now we're complaining because rep *isn't* being lost. (Note: This is a legitimate issue and I mean no disrespect to @Oded, but couldn't help laughing by butt off when I saw this given the current state of things).

Comment: @casperOne - Yeah... I guess I am complaining because I can't see the reputation gained ;)

Comment: @casperOne - I just hope [Nick](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver) won't have a fit over this one... The work done was a massive job, hope this isn't going to be one of those bugs that take days to work out.

Comment: @Oded - I *think* this was solved by the last round of changes, still a few bugs to stomp out though, so not closing this juuuuuust yet.

Comment: @NickCraver - Figured this was an edge case (downvoted post deleted and user hit rep cap on upvotes), so would probably not have a test case...

Comment: @NickCraver - This is still happening... added todays info.

Comment: @Oded - apologies I'm just now getting to this...going down the list, if this happens again can you ping me via comment?  You were recalced due to us fixing reputation duplication on migrated answers yesterday, so now the data I need to debug this isn't there.

Comment: @NickCraver - Ping... You can take a look at the current state of things (discrepancy of 3 rep points, just around the rep cap, with another 5 forecast). As for "just now getting to this" - not a problem at all. I am sure there are other, higher, priorities.

Comment: @NickCraver - This just changed (2 hours after the last upvote) and got corrected. Don't know if it was you, triggering a recalc.

Comment: @NickCraver - Ping 2. The forecast 5 discrepancy has just occurred... I have 151950 rep with 260 rep for today appearing in the audit page, but 151945 with 240 rep for today (-15 from unaccept, but the remaining 5 from the issue I have described) on the profile page.

Comment: @Oded - I see the issue finally, thanks for the quick ping...makes it much easier to see what's happening.  I'll be rolling out a fix in the next build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, some deletion race conditions could previously result in votes not being counted (because the rep cap for the day was mis-calculated in realtime).  In short, this is now accounted for.